# How to link C++17 stdc++fs library to mixed language (C++ and Fortran) CMake project?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, fortran, c++17

I am trying to add some Fortran code to my C++ project with CMake. The project uses the C++17 filesystem library with no problem until I add this Fortran file to the executable, which seems to break the linker. I have stripped the issue down to a minimal example with no functionality other than producing the error.

Original CMakeLists.txt (compiles fine):

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.10.2 )

enable_language( Fortran )
project( Minimal C CXX Fortran )

# Using C++17.
set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17 )
set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON )

add_executable( Executable test.cpp )
target_link_libraries( Executable stdc++fs )
```

Modified CMakeLists.txt (added test.f90, no longer compiles):

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.10.2 )

enable_language( Fortran )
project( Minimal C CXX Fortran )

# Using C++17.
set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17 )
set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON )

add_executable( Executable test.cpp test.f90 )
target_link_libraries( Executable stdc++fs )
```

The latter fails compilation/linking with the following error (identical to the error if the `target_link_libraries` line is omitted from the former):

```
CMakeFiles/Minimal.dir/test.cpp.o: In function `std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::path<char [5], std::filesystem::__cxx11::path>(char const (&) [5], std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::format)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx114pathC2IA5_cS1_EERKT_NS1_6formatE[_ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx114pathC5IA5_cS1_EERKT_NS1_6formatE]+0x6d): undefined reference to `std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/Minimal.dir/build.make:120: recipe for target 'Minimal' failed
make[2]: *** [Minimal] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Minimal.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Minimal.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it? I have tried `set_property( TARGET Executable PROPERTY LINK_LANGUAGE Fortran )`, but that didn't work.

```
add_library( TestLibrary test.f90 )
...
target_link_libraries( Executable TestLibrary )
```

also didn't work. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

For full reference:

test.cpp:

```
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path test ("test");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

test.f90:

```
subroutine do_nothing()

end
```

command line call:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-8 ..
make
```

My GCC version is 8.3.0.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Your second (modified) `CMakeLists.txt` works fine for me. `make VERBOSE=1` output: `/usr/bin/g++-8 -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/Executable.dir/test.cpp.o -c /tmp/0/test.cpp`, `/usr/bin/f95 -c /tmp/0/test.f90 -o CMakeFiles/Executable.dir/test.f90.o`, and `/usr/bin/g++-8     CMakeFiles/Executable.dir/test.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Executable.dir/test.f90.o  -o Executable -lstdc++fs -lgfortran -lquadmath`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may well be a consequence of mixing of different compiler versions. You are overriding just the C++ compiler, but also the C and Fortran ones should be consistent with it. I am able to get a similar error message during linking when I use `gcc` and `gfortran` from GCC 8.2, but `g++` from GCC 9.2 (with CMake 3.10.2).

This is because CMake gets some important paths from the C compiler (like the default directory where to look for the runtime libraries). But if you compiled your C++ code with a different C++ compiler, it uses headers of the latter, resulting in the incompatibility.

You should always use consistent set of compilers; in this case:

```
cmake \
    -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-8 \
    -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-8 \
    -D CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=gfortran-8 \
    ..
```